# Visual Studio 2017: "Extension Microsoft integration services projects 2.2 likely caused 43 seconds of unresponsiveness"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, ssis

### extension Microsoft integration services projects 2.2 likely caused 43 seconds of unresponsiveness

ISSUE:

1. Visual Studio is VERY slow for Microsoft Integration Services with VS 2017.
2. not possible to click "Edit script"-button on Script-component.
3. Getting message: "extension Microsoft integration services projects 2.2 likely caused 43 seconds of unresponsiveness"

DONE:

1. tried to repair VS in Visual Studio Installer
2. uninstalled and installed SSDT

VS VERSION:

-Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 Version 15.9.6
- VisualStudio.15.Release/15.9.6+28307.344 Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.7.03190

EXTENSION VERSION:

- Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools. 15.1.61901.03220.
- Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services . 15.0.1100.123
- Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services . 15.0.1300.59
- Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services . Version 15.0.900.163

["Edit Script- button disabled"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEjJg.png)

[Error msg for Integration Sefvices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MGkH.png)

[About Visual Studio, versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TeZX.png)

Comment: Not sure if you ever got your answer (6 months later!) but this still happens to me and i have to reinstall SQL Server Data Tools to get things going again.
[https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017) Would love to know if you've managed to find a more permanent solution to this.

Comment: the solution for me was to start using Visual Studio 2019 instead

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem in SSDT 2017 ... This post by SQL Girl explains that what is going on is that connections are being validated ... there are number of ways to treat this ... http://thesqlgirl.com/2016/09/17/ssis-package-validation/ ...I like Validate External Metadata: False or Work Offline: True